# menukeys with LinuxLibertine/Biolinum

Tags: libertine

I'm trying to use Linux Libertine/Biolinum in combination with the menukeys package. Unfortunately, switching between the default font (everything scaled properly) and Libertine causes the predefined keys to shrink unproportionally compared to the text size.
Any clues what's happening here?

[image: Libertine and menukeys]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatextra}
% toggle on / off
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum O}
%

\usepackage[os=mac]{menukeys}
\begin{document}

\keys{\cmd+\ctrl+A}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Do you have the newest versions of the fonts? Some older fonts had wrong ex values.

Comment: Also works fine for me. If you have an up to date TeX install you could try to use the `libertine` package (it loads the OpenType fonts for you and provides a recent version of Libertine/Biolinum).

Comment: Indeed, i had to update the `libertine` package. Now it works flawlessly.

Comment: Voting to close, because questions answered by _you have to update_ are _too localized_ by definition, I think. That’s not saying that this is a bad question, however!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with current TeXLive or MiKTeX you do not need an additional package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}

\LKeyCommand+\LKeyCtrlX{A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But what would you do if you like to change the border color, or replace the `+` by something else? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the alternative but i like the formatting capabilities of the menukey package as well as its add. features (listing a menu  / path sequence). Mh, not sure if i'm doing it right but i'm going to accept this answer to mark the question answered. But the primary solution to my problem was to update the libertine fonts, as stated by Ulrike.